# How I can update inventory stock after purchase - asp.net webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inventory-management

Can someone help me? I can't update inventory records after purchase, it shows me null error. I can't retrieve the original data from the database.
Here is my code:

```cs
DBContext db = new DBContext(); 
var inTB = db.InventoryTBs.Where(s => s.id == customerTB.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault(); 
inTB.Quantity += customerTB.CQuantity; 
db.InventoryTBs.Add(inTB); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To modify existing record obtained by the context just call `SaveChanges()`:

```cs
var inTB = db.InventoryTBs.Where(s => s.id == customerTB.CustomerID).FirstOrDefault(); 
if (inTB  != null)
{
    // Modifying existing record
    inTB.Quantity += customerTB.CQuantity;    
}
else
{   
    // Adding a new record
    db.InventoryTBs.Add(new InventoryTB() { Quantity = customerTB.CQuantity; /* set another properties */});
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

In your case a record with `customerTB.CustomerID` does not exist. Therefore, perhaps it's necessary to create new one and then add it to the `InventoryTBs`.

For additional information see: [Modifying data via the DbContext](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data)

Comment: Thank you for your help. that was the answer i was looking for. it worked well, thanks again.